# How to append SVG to the page using D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

So I have a .js file that contains a simple SVG that creates a square. Code below:

```
function load(){
 var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

 var foo = document.getElementById("printSquare");
 var bar = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
 var svgSquare = d3.select("div.output svg")
 s.appendChild(svgSquare)
 foo.appendChild(bar);

 var square = svg.select("rect")
 square.attr("width", 200)
 square.attr("height", 200)
}
window.onload = load;
```

I want to append this square to an html file so I can open it in a browser and see the square. My HTML code as of right now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="drawSquare.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="printSquare"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s8capLx3/2/

If you want to just create a square and nothing else, there are 2 ways to go about it...

1. Use d3 symbols or 2. Use a rect (like you tried)

   ```
   var data = [0];
   var svg = d3.select('#printSquare').append('svg').attr('width',400).attr('height',200);

   //symbols approach
   svg.selectAll('.symbol')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate('+(i*20+20 )+','+30+')';})
   .attr('d', d3.symbol().type( function(d,i) { return d 3.symbols[3];}).size("200"));

   //rect approach
   svg.append("rect")
   .attr("x", "200")
   .attr("y", "10")
   .attr("width", "75")
   .attr("height", "75")
   .attr("fill", "black");
   ```